# Symfony 4 doctrine many to many with findby -> Column not found: 1054

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony4, findby

**I'm trying to make a many to many join with a Doctrine findBy()**

```
$articles = $entityManager->getRepository(Articles::class)
->findBy(['rubriquesrubriques'=>$id],['idarticles'=>"ASC"]);
```

**But I get**

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'SELECT t0.idarticles AS idarticles_1, 
t0.thetitle AS thetitle_2, t0.theslug AS theslug_3, t0.thedescription AS 
thedescription_4, t0.thedate AS thedate_5, t0.users_idusers AS users_idusers_6 
FROM articles t0 WHERE
 articles_has_rubriques.rubriques_idrubriques = ? 
ORDER BY t0.idarticles ASC' with params ["2"]:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ
 'articles_has_rubriques.rubriques_idrubriques' inconnu dans where clause
```

**The column articles_has_rubriques.rubriques_idrubriques exists in my DB, 
but I don't see the INNER JOIN !**

When I make my many to many with a simple Find():

```
$articles = $entityManager->getRepository(Articles::class)->find($id);
```

**The query is correct!**

```
SELECT t0.idrubriques AS idrubriques_1, 
t0.thertitle AS thertitle_2 
FROM 
rubriques t0 
INNER JOIN articles_has_rubriques ON t0.idrubriques =
articles_has_rubriques.rubriques_idrubriques 
WHERE articles_has_rubriques.articles_idarticles = ?
```

**is it impossible to perform my many2many query with a findBy in the 4.1.6 version of Symfony???**

This is my ORM relation:

In entity **Rubriques.php**:

```
 /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Articles", mappedBy="rubriquesrubriques")
 */
private $articlesarticles;
```

In entity **Articles.php**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Rubriques", inversedBy="articlesarticles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_has_rubriques",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articles_idarticles", referencedColumnName="idarticles")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rubriques_idrubriques", referencedColumnName="idrubriques")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $rubriquesrubriques;
```

**Thank you so much**

Answer (score 0):

My question was stupid :

I'have an easy way to do that:

```
$rubriqueActu = $entityManager->getRepository(Rubriques::class)->find($id);
$articles = $rubriqueActu->getArticlesarticles();
```

SQL:

```
SELECT t0.idarticles AS idarticles_1, t0.thetitle AS thetitle_2, 
 t0.theslug AS theslug_3, t0.thedescription AS thedescription_4,
 t0.thedate AS thedate_5, t0.users_idusers AS users_idusers_6
FROM articles t0 INNER JOIN articles_has_rubriques 
ON t0.idarticles = articles_has_rubriques.articles_idarticles 
WHERE articles_has_rubriques.rubriques_idrubriques = ?
```